# Tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Stuck on Purple Screen

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, amd-cpu, nvidia-rtx

hope you could help a noob installing Linux Ubuntu. I installed the amd Version with Nvidia Drivers but I stuck on a purple Screen where I can move Mouse but nothing else is shown, tried to disable Nvidia Drivers but then nothing is working and I stuck on the same and when I reinstall without this drivers I stuck in black loading screen for hours...

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl + Alt + F6. Then follow steps 6,7,8 [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-ubuntu-18-04-live-boot-leads-to-blank-screen-duplicate/). When you finish type "sudo reboot" and it should reboot fine

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.